# 9 posiciones css básicas fixed dentro de div dentro de div

Tags: html, css

Me gustaría que me ayudaran a colocar 9 posiciones básicas dentro de un div dentro de un div como aparece en el ejemplo. Las 9 posiciones serían:
Superior Derecho, Superior Izquierdo, Superior Centro.
Centro Derecho, Centro Izquierdo, Centro Derecho.
Inferior Derecho, Inferior Izquierdo, Inferior Derecho.
Como los divs son de distinto tamaño y muchas veces sin especificar (algunos serán texto) supongo que tendría que ir en porcentajes.
El div padre tampoco tendrá un ancho especificado pues también obedecerá a la composición de un texto.
Gracias.

```css
body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#header{width:100%; border-bottom:red 1px solid; position:fixed; height:30px;z-index:1000;  margin-top:0;}
#wraper{width:100%;  padding-top:30px;}
.basic_unit{width:800px; height:1200px; border:rgba(0,0,0,1.00) solid 1px; margin:auto;}
.basic{width:200px; height:200px; background:yellow;}
.fixed {position:fixed;}
.top_left{ top:30; right-margin:0%;}
.top_right{ top:30px; right:0%;}
#container{overflow:hidden;display:inline-block; margin:auto;}
#wraper{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wraper">
<div id="container">
<div class="basic fixed top_left"></div>
<div class="basic fixed top_right"></div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: El alto de los divs es variables? Si ese es el caso deberias usar una librería como [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) ya que ajustar anchos variables y alturas variables puede ser un poquito complicado. Si las alturas son iguales se puede lograr solo con CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de cómo se podría lograr sin porcentajes. Esta solución se basa en:

- Hacer que el `div` interior ocupe el tamaño completo del `div` exterior
- Añadir posición relativa (`position:relative`) al `div` interior
- La clase `basic` identificará las 9 posiciones y tendrá posición absoluta (`position:absolute`). De este modo siempre se ajustará dentro del `div` padre.
- Definir las 6 posiciones básicas:

  - Arriba/top: que tendrá `top:0`.
  - Abajo/bottom: que tendrá `bottom:0`.
  - Centro/center: que tendrá `top:50%` y una traslación de -50% horizontalmente.
  - Izquierda/left: que tendrá `left:0`.
  - Derecha/right: que tendrá `right:0`.
  - Centro/middle: que tendrá `left:50%` y una traslación de -50% verticalmente.
- En el caso de que la clase se Centro-Centro (center middle), se redefine la traslación para que sea -50% horizontal y verticalmente.

Ahora sólo queda añadir los 9 `div` para las 9 posiciones, combinando las diferentes clases verticales y horizontales y dejando que el navegador se encargue de renderizarlas en su lugar adecuado.

He cambiado un poco los estilos para que esté un poco más limpio. El resultado se vería así:

```css
body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#header{width:100%; border-bottom:red 1px solid; position:fixed; height:30px;z-index:1000;  margin-top:0;}
#wraper{width:100%;  padding-top:30px; text-align:center; }
.basic_unit{width:800px; height:1200px; border:rgba(0,0,0,1.00) solid 1px; margin:auto;}
.basic{width:200px; height:200px; background:yellow;}
.basic2{width:200px; height:200px; background:red;}
.fixed {position:fixed;}
.center_center{ display:inline-block;z-index:100;}
#container{overflow:auto; background:rgba(255,0,234,0.20); display:inline-block;}
.left { left:0; }
.right { right:0; }
.center { left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, 0); }
.top { top:0; }
.bottom { bottom:0; }
.middle { top:50%; transform:translate(0, -50%); }
.center.middle { transform:translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="wraper">
<div id="container">

<div class="basic fixed top left"></div>
<div class="basic fixed top right"></div>
<div class="basic fixed top center"></div>
<div class="basic fixed middle left"></div>
<div class="basic fixed middle right"></div>
<div class="basic fixed middle center"></div>
<div class="basic fixed bottom left"></div>
<div class="basic fixed bottom right"></div>
<div class="basic fixed bottom center"></div>

<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta pero los divs deben tener posición fija con respecto a la pantalla y no salirse del ancho del div padre por lo que no se resuelve el problema que precisamente deriva de estos condicionantes.

Comment: @IvanSoler He cambiado el código un poco: la posición fija con respecto a la pantalla se consigue al ponerle posición fija al `div` exterior, y el ancho de los `.basic` no excede el del padre

Comment: Nada @AlvaroMontoro me resulta imposible compatibilizar lo que propones con mi estructura ya que al "container" le das ancho y altura fija y al wraper también pero en mi caso estas características dependen del contenido de éstos. La complicación del asunto en realidad es esta sumada a la premisa de que los divs  que busco posicionar no se salgan del ancho del div container pese a estar fijos con respecto a la pantalla.